# Chrome Extension rejected due to Firebase remote code

Tags: javascript, firebase, webpack, google-chrome-extension, firebase-authentication

I have a chrome MV3 extension that is being rejected due to remotely hosted code. I'm using webpack and Firebase.

```
import {
    getAuth
  } from 'firebase/auth';
```

I'm trying to submit an update now, but Google keeps denying it.  I've tracked it down to this import.  Webpack is including code for recaptcha.

```
const RECAPTCHA_BASE = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?';
.....
const url = `${RECAPTCHA_BASE}?${(0,_firebase_util__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.querystring)({
                onload: _JSLOAD_CALLBACK,
                render: 'explicit',
                hl
            })}`;
            _loadJS(url).catch(() => {
                clearTimeout(networkTimeout);
                reject(_createError(auth, "internal-error" /* AuthErrorCode.INTERNAL_ERROR */));
            });
```

I'm not using recaptcha in my authentication process.  DO you think I'd be OK to change this URL to local and not break anything else?

In looking at the packed code more, It seems that the RecaptchaVerifier is used with phone number verification.  I'm not using that. I'm only using Google authentication. is there any way I can change this to be excluded in my webpack setup?

Comment: Did you found solution for this?

Comment: Not really.  I ended up just modifying the webpack generated code and taking off the remove reference.  My code doesn't use it, so nothing breaks even though it's not there.  Definitely not a great solution.